# unable to display a children span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.disable').click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).parent().next('.span_data_a').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="col-md-6">
  <!-- MODIFICA FORM -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edita" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="Modifica le impostazioni di questo form"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edita</button>

  <!-- SCARICA DATI -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary risultati" data-value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="Visualizza e scarica i risultati di questo form">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true"></span> Risultati</button>

  <!-- DISABILITA FORM -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disable" data-value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="Disabilita caricamento dati con questo form">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" aria-hidden="true"></span> Disabilita
  </button>

  <!-- RIABILITA FORM -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary enable" data-value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="Abilita caricamento dati con questo form" style="display: none">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span> Abilita
  </button>

  <!-- SEGNALA UN BUG -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="Contattaci se stai riscontrando problemi con questo form">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Segnala un bug
  </button>

  <!-- FORM PRIVATO O PUBBLICO -->
  <!--CAMBIO DATA VALIDITA' -->
  <span class="span_data_a" style="display: none"><br><br><label for="data-a">Fine validit&agrave;: </label>
  <input type="text" id="data-a"></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to display the span with class "span_data_a" when I click the button with class "disable".
I tried different combinations of .next, .parent, .find but I am not able to trigger the span to display.

What am I doing wrong?
These buttons are in a row of a table. So there will be many of these and I need to show only the span related to the clicked button. So this code will show all of them

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('.span_data_a').toggle();`

Comment: Well, first, the code shown is invalid due to an extra `</tr>` (or a missing `<tr>` and `<table>` and `</table>`) but in any case, `next` works on the same level of the hierarchy, and your `span class="span_data_a"` is at the same level as your `button`, and you go up one level with `parent()`. So go up with `parent()`, but then use `find()` to go back down.

Comment: @j08691 the right combination is the one that you haven't thought about :-) thanks it works as espected!

Comment: @HereticMonkey the code is an extract of the whole code that is actually fully valid. but thanks for noticing